# Can't run stripe-ruby-mock ony my localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write some integrations tests to stripe payments in my app. I found some nice tutorial:

http://www.jeffthomas.xyz/integration-tests-with-stripe/

I've made everything the same like in this tutorial but when I run my specs they gaves me the following error:

```
Daemon has started successfully
Killing server at ./stripe-mock-server.pid
Stopped PID: 5650 at ./stripe-mock-server.pid
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/mateusz/projekty/bp-web/coverage. 351 / 437 LOC (80.32%) covered.
/home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec': PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
:               SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM pg_class c
              LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
              WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','v','m') -- (r)elation/table, (v)iew, (m)aterialized view
              AND c.relname = 'schema_migrations'
              AND n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:105:in `table_exists?'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:843:in `get_all_versions'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:855:in `needs_migration?'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:397:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:640:in `suppress_messages'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `method_missing'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `maintain_test_schema!'
    from /home/mateusz/projekty/bp-web/spec/rails_helper.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mateusz/projekty/bp-web/spec/features/billing_details_update_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/mateusz/projekty/bp-web/spec/features/billing_details_update_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same problem - even following the same tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem but forgot to write answer here:

https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock/issues/202#issuecomment-81462909

Answer (score 0):

if want to spawn the server after rails is already initialized (e.g. in `spec/rails_helper.rb` or elsewhere), you can tell active record to reconnect and it will work:

```
StripeMock.spawn_server
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```